# In mobX can a store "listen" to other another store, and execute a query whenever the other store changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, store, mobx

Say I have a store, which has a list of organizations, the user can "select" organizations, which are then stored in the "filter" array.

```
export class OrganizationStore extends ArrayStore {
    //organizations = new Map();

    constructor( ...args) {
        super(args);
        this.organizations = new Map();
        this.filter = [];
        this.getter_url = '/organization/get-organizations';
    }

    async getData() {
        const full_url = new URL(this.getter_url);
        const options = {};
        options.method = 'GET';
        options.credentials = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'same-origin' : 'include';

        const response = await fetch(full_url, options);
        if (response.ok) {
            const d = await response.json();
            this.buildStore(d);
        }

    }

    buildStore(values) {
        this.organizations.clear();
        for (const {id, name} of values) {
            this.organizations.set(id, new Organization(id, name));
        }
    }

    get count() {
        return this.organizations.size;
    }
}

decorate(OrganizationStore, {
    organizations: observable,
    filter: observable,
    count: computed,
});



export class Organization {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Another store also exists

```
export class UserStore extends ArrayStore {
    constructor(organizationStore, ...args) {
        super(args);
        this.users = [];
        this.getter_url = '/users/get-users';
        this.organizationStore = organizationStore;
    }

    async getData() {
        const full_url = new URL(this.getter_url);
        const options = {};
        options.method = 'GET';
        options.credentials = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'same-origin' : 'include';

        query = {filter: this.organizationStore.filter()};
        //how to make this line "observe" the original store

        Object.keys(query).forEach(key => full_url.searchParams.append(key, options.query[key]));


        const response = await fetch(full_url, options);
        if (response.ok) {
            const d = await response.json();
            this.buildStore(d);
        }


    }
}
```

Now (how) can I make the store automaticaly refresh itself (let getData rerun once `organizationStore.filter[]` changes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for [reactions](https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html).

> Reaction - A variation on autorun that gives more fine grained control on which observables will be tracked. It takes two functions, the first one (the data function) is tracked and returns data that is used as input for the second one, the effect function.

```
export class UserStore extends ArrayStore {
    constructor(organizationStore, ...args) {
        super(args);
        this.users = [];
        this.getter_url = '/users/get-users';
        this.organizationStore = organizationStore;

        // Dispose of this when done with it
        const disposer = reaction(
            () => this.organizationStore.filter.length,
            () => this.getData()
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Another option, if you want event more control, is to use [observe](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html)

```
const disposer = observe(this.organizationStore.filter, (change) => {
    // Change is an object with a couple properties that describe what has changed and how
});
```

But I think reaction is fine for you.

Comment: Well filter length wouldn't change always, it's actually more common that the whole filter array is changed (and size kept equal)

Comment: @paul23 The first function is anything that should trigger an update. Perhaps it would be better to use observe in this case, so that you can apply additional constraints, like if the new array equals the old, or if all elements are the same, etc. If you look at the observe docs, there is a table which contains useful info [here](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#event-overview)